# Show or open or nivigate to UITabBarController form Viewcontroller like login page in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

My request is very simple and I am new in ios developing,
I want to show  UITabBarController after login successfully

```
@IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender: Any) {
//correct me here!
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabbar:UITabBarController? = (storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiveViewController") as? UITabBarController)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar!, animated: true)

}
```

main.storyBoard storyBoard:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This

```
navigationController?
```

is `nil` in

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(tabbar!, animated: true)
```

You need

```
let tabbar = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LiveViewController") as! UITabBarController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbar)
nav.isNavigationBarHidden = true
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = nav
```